# is it possible to find out a partition of $[a,b]$

Tags: analysis

Let, $f:[a,b]$$\rightarrow$$\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Is it possible to find out a partition of $[a,b]$ such that $f$ is monotone there?

I am stuck here. How to proceed from here?

Comment: Do you mean partition = open / closed subinterval?

Comment: yeah! Open or closed whatever!

Answer (score 5):

Not in general. There are continuous functions which are not monotonic on any interval. For example the Weierstrass function.

Comment: Weierstrass function means that function which is cont everywhere but differentiable nowhere?

Comment: Yes I do mean that one. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function

Comment: one thing may be I am not getting how to show that it is not monotone?

Comment: I think this result can be found in Classics on Fractals.

Comment: Fits my expectation. Continuity of the function is not strong enough, continuity of the derivative would be good. But we do not have that.

Comment: @mvw You may find it interesting that even the assumption of differentiability is not quite enough. http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1976-056-01/S0002-9939-1976-0396870-2/S0002-9939-1976-0396870-2.pdf

Comment: Very interesting, but I lack the tools used there. Funny is "by pushing and crushing it is not hard to prove..", which seems to refer to some technique I do not know.

Comment: Since no one seems to have said the name, Lebesgue's differentiation theorem says that a monotone function is differentiable a.e. (See Royden for example). So any nowhere-differentiable function is non-monotone on any subinterval.

Comment: Good point InTransit!

Comment: User71352 many thnx for posting the link for the Weil paper. The bare statement of the theorem is mindboggling and audacious!

Comment: @InTransit You're welcome.